# ReactJS doesn't recognize a value in an object in an array

Tags: json, reactjs, express

I am making a web app with express + react and I'm sending JSON data.
I am fetching this data with axios and using setState to set the messages variable to response.data.messages

```
{
  "messages":{
    "message":{
      "username":"Khigoris"
    }
  }
}
```

and it doesn't let me do this

```
<p>{messages.message.username}</p>
```

But it says it is undefined

I am new to using JSON so I think it's the syntax but I need help.

Comment: There is no array in the code presented here. Arrays are delimited by square brackets `[ ... ]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the messages object is wrapped in another object, i.e your code looks like:

```
const value = {
  "messages":{
    "message":{
      "username":"Khigoris"
    }
  }
}
```

So you should use:

```
<p>{value.messages.message.username}</p>
```